# is there a way to make robot framework code run a failed testcase multiple times

Tags: robotframework

I will like to run this multiple times to test what happens when users try to login with wrong credentials many times. The problem is that this runs once, and if i try duplicating it again, it doesnt run the rest of the code.

The result is supposed to be
'''
HTTP error 401 Unauthorized, Attempt 1
'''
but i will like to see 10 attempts
I have tried this but it fails
'''
${result}=    Run special command    -k    --url    https://${url}    auth    login    ${username}    -p${password}
'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the same question you most likely presented here https://forum.robotframework.org/t/i-want-to-test-many-attempted-failed-login/4781 - I already suggested to look into  `Run Keyword And Expect Error`

But apparently that was too cumbersome.

```
*** Variables ***
${url}    http://localhost
${username}   nobody
${password}   notmypassword

*** Keywords ***
Run special command
  [arguments]   ${arg1}   ${arg2}   ${arg3}   ${arg4}   ${arg5}   ${arg6}   ${arg7}
  [return]    "Nothing to see here folks"
  Log To Console     ${arg1} ${arg2} ${arg3} ${arg4} ${arg5} ${arg6} ${arg7}
  Fail    This is the error message for failure


*** Test Cases ***

Doesnt Repeat Failure
  Log To Console   \nThis does show because its start of the testcase
  ${result}=    Run special command    -k    --url    https://${url}    auth    login    ${username}    -p${password}
  ${result}=    Run special command    -k    --url    https://${url}    auth    login    ${username}    -p${password}
  ${result}=    Run special command    -k    --url    https://${url}    auth    login    ${username}    -p${password}
  Log To Console   \nThis will not be shown because run special command fails

Does Repeat Failure

  Log To Console   \nThis does show because its start of the testcase

  ${result}=    Run Keyword And Expect Error  *
  ...   Run special command    -k    --url    https://${url}    auth    login    ${username}    -p${password}

  ${result}=    Run Keyword And Expect Error  *
  ...   Run special command    -k    --url    https://${url}    auth    login    ${username}    -p${password}

  ${result}=    Run Keyword And Expect Error  *
  ...   Run special command    -k    --url    https://${url}    auth    login    ${username}    -p${password}

  Log To Console   \nThis will be shown because we where expecting the error and last call returned a value: : ${result}

Does Repeat Failure with for loop
  Log To Console   \nThis does show because its start of the testcase
  FOR    ${idx}    IN RANGE    10
    Log To Console    \nIteration: ${idx}
    ${result}=    Run Keyword And Expect Error  *
    ...   Run special command    -k    --url    https://${url}    auth    login    ${username}    -p${password}
  END
  Log To Console   \nThis will be shown because we where expecting the error and last call returned a value: : ${result}
```

This example has 3 test cases, one that you are trying to do that will fail if you run it .. 2 other cases that will call your "Run Special command" that always fails but the test itself doesnt fail because the test code *EXPECTS* that the keyword call will fail with given parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a keyword that does the login, and then a single test case that calls this keyword multiple times.